# How do I track progress on a queue job?

Tags: message-queue, laravel-5.1

I am using the the database queue driver in laravel to run jobs in the background.

One of my jobs creates a given number (thousands to hundred thousands) records in the database. I wrapped the code for this job in a transaction so that in case the job failed, the database writes would not be commited.

Initially to track progress of the job, i thought i would count the number of created records, divide by total number of expected records then display that in a ui as percentage against each job such that users can know how much longer they have to wait.

This doesn't work because the tables are locked during the transaction.

Am wondering if anybody knows how track progress on a queued job

Answer (score 7):

For the ones who stumble on this question, there is a package which allows that: https://github.com/imTigger/laravel-job-status

Answer (score 1):

As given in http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#job-events

The Queue::after method can be called once a job has completed successfully

As given in http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#failed-job-events

The Queue::failing method can be called when a queued job fails

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i know about the methods. What i need is progress of individual jobs while they are running, for example i would like a way to know when a job is 10% done and so on

Comment: @ErnestOkot I do have a similar kind of requirement what did you use to get the status of the job like 10% done 20% done and so on?